# Convert json array to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have one json array

```
 jsoncast_arr = new array();
 jsoncast_arr.push( value +":"+ value1 );


 ["C :1b3ea8fa-89e9-4dc4-8e95-7ee9575cc391", "C :ed5817e6-3bfe-4bcf-9631-
 d091fc3a2d3b", "C :8c43b885-e6cd-457c-bf1d-4475f85b905f", "C :cf0eecd3-9bf1-4435-
 b6be-50da8b09662b", "C :74efc501-21b5-49d9-b95c-17549ccda8dc", "C :ecb67dfb-
 2d3c-4aea-9072-5339df4955a2", "C :c1f2faa6-49ba-4dbb-bea9-08eb1ffd426d", "C 
 :06fe9afb-1850-4470-b365-2318d995a647", "C :fa5f274d-fd6c-4904-b3d6-c20edf45efdf"]
```

when i parse the json , i need to convert this into like that, may be an json object in javascript

```
{"c"=>"1b3ea8fa-89e9-4dc4-8e95-7ee9575cc391","c"=>"ed5817e6-3bfe-4bcf-9631-
d091fc3a2d3b"}
```

here this JSON.stringify(jsoncast_arr)  not getting above like that.?

Comment: That's not a JSON array.

Comment: A single index can not store different values.

Comment: Won't work like this, you always have the same key (index).

Comment: why can't you just do `object[value] = value1;`

Comment: Does `jsoncast_arr.push( value +":"+ value1 );` creates json like the one you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want an array of objects:

```
[
{"c":"1b3ea8fa-89e9-4dc4-8e95-7ee9575cc391"},
{"c":"ed5817e6-3bfe-4bcf-9631-d091fc3a2d3b"}
]
```

Comment: yes, like that, so after that i think when i use json parse will work

Comment: why do you need json.parse? It seems that you already have the single values in JS. So simply type varname[varname.length] = {value:value1};